# is it possible to cache a dynamic web page?

Tags: php, javascript, caching, dynamic

Is it possible to cache a dynamic webpage if javascript is used to alter the display or write new innerHTML into the page. For example maybe some ajax runs and fetches some info from the database that is then displayed dynamically on the page by rewriting the innerHTML of a div.

Is it possible to cache the final html and serve that up instead of recreating it each time. 
Thanks,

Dan

Comment: You probably want to look into using localStorage: http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.

It is common with auto-complete text input boxes to cache the results so that hitting backspace or delete does not re-send requests to the server.

How to do it?  Just read `innerHTML` from the DOM tree and save somewhere, in a JavaScript variable or even in HTML5 local storage.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I can rebuild the whole thing by looking at what I write into the innerHTML and store it. That might work. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how dynamic your page actually is especially if you're displaying information directly relating to the user, i.e. "G'Day Flungabunga, how are thing's in Sydney, Australia" by means of an ajax request.

In my experience the solutions and techniques employed to achieve caching of these results and still maintaining javascript as the core mechanism became overly complicated and brittle.

To achieve this kind of behaviour and be able to cache these results effectively we employed Varnish Cache and it's ESI (Edge Side Includes) capabilities.

I know this answer if off topic to some degree, however you may find that looking at a different mechanism may give you a more graceful solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Varnish.